# How can I add margin notes on inner side of a page in two sides mode?

Tags: marginpar, double-sided

How can I add margin notes on inner side of a page only for even pages in two sides mode?

Answer (score 12):

Use `\reversemarginpar` to change to side of `\marginpar`s. This is an global setting, i.e. won't be limited to the current group/environment. However `\normalmarginpar` switches back to the normal side.

Answer (score 6):

The [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes offer the option `twoside=semi` which will typeset running headers/footers like in `twoside` mode, but set page margins and position `\marginpar`s as if in `oneside` mode (i.e., *"on [the] inner side of a page only for even pages"*).

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

Some text.\marginpar{Some text.} \lipsum[1-5]

Some text.\marginpar{Some text.} \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```