# Left marginnote does not work

Tags: marginnote

I badly need to have marginal notes on the *left* margin. 
The command `\marginpar` does not work.
Supposedly, `\marginnote` works, and this needs the `marginnote` package.
OK, I tried, but nothing happens.
Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
This is normal text. 
\marginnote[left]{right}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, anything I put on the `[left]` field is ignored. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [The comment by Raphael to use \normalmarginpar to switch back](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22538/how-can-i-add-margin-notes-on-inner-side-of-a-page-in-two-sides-mode/22546#22546) ended several days of frustration, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

`\reversemarginpar` is used to switch between the "traditional" right-side margin paragraph and a left-side alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,marginnote}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{showframe,marginnote}
\begin{document}
This is normal text. \marginpar{right} \par
This is normal text. \marginnote{right}

\reversemarginpar
This is normal text. \marginpar{left} \par
This is normal text. \marginnote{left}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Use `\normalmarginpar` to switch back](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22546/3213).