# Making marginnote to appear either side of twocolumn, twoside document

Tags: two-column, double-sided, marginpar, marginnote

I have the following MWE in which the `\marginnote` need to appear at correct margin. For example the margin notes **one, two, three** and **four** need to appear on left margin of first page. In the second page the margin notes **thirteen** and **fourteen** should appear on right side.

The command `\reversemarginpar` corrects this, but I need to reset on next column. I am not able to use the `twocolumn` document class option as I am using `\twocolumn[]` to set the title part of the document.

I will not be able to use other class files. Is there an easy way to put the margin notes to the respective margins.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\twocolumn[{%
\hrulefill\medskip\par
\lipsum[1]
\hrulefill
\vspace*{2pc}
}]


\section{Two}\label{s2}
\marginnote{One}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Two}\lipsum[2] 
\marginnote{Three}\lipsum[3]
\marginnote{Four}\lipsum[4]
\marginnote{Five}\lipsum[5]
\marginnote{Six}\lipsum[6]
\marginnote{Seven}\lipsum[7]

\section{Three}\label{s3}
\marginnote{Eight}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Nine}\lipsum[2] 
\marginnote{Ten}\lipsum[3]
\marginnote{Eleven}\lipsum[4]
\marginnote{Twelve}\lipsum[5]
\marginnote{Thirteen}\lipsum[6]
\marginnote{Fourteen}\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

---

There are certain post available here with `\marginnote` which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Does it have to happen automatically, or is specifying the margin as an argument an option?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It should happen automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldmarginnote\marginnote
\renewcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
   \ifodd\value{page}
     \if@firstcolumn\reversemarginpar\fi
   \else
     \if@firstcolumn\else\reversemarginpar\fi
   \fi
   \oldmarginnote{#1}%
   \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmarginnote\marginnote
\renewcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
   \ifodd\value{page}
     \if@firstcolumn\reversemarginpar\fi
   \else
     \if@firstcolumn\else\reversemarginpar\fi
   \fi
   \oldmarginnote{#1}%
   \endgroup%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\sloppy

\twocolumn[{%
\hrulefill\medskip\par
\lipsum[1]
\hrulefill
\vspace*{2pc}
}]


\section{Two}\label{s2}
\marginnote{One}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Two}\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{Three}\lipsum[3]
\marginnote{Four}\lipsum[4]
\marginnote{Five}\lipsum[5]
\marginnote{Six}\lipsum[6]
\marginnote{Seven}\lipsum[7]


\section{Three}\label{s3}
\marginnote{Eight}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Nine}\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{Ten}\lipsum[3]
\marginnote{Eleven}\lipsum[4]
\marginnote{Twelve}\lipsum[5]
\marginnote{Thirteen}\lipsum[6]
\marginnote{Fourteen}\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

To avoid having paragraphs at the beginning of a page with an orphan margin note in the previous page, you can load the `needspace` package and add `\needspace{\baselineskip}` to the re-definition of `\marginnote`

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldmarginnote\marginnote
\renewcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
   \ifodd\value{page}
     \if@firstcolumn\reversemarginpar\fi
   \else
     \if@firstcolumn\else\reversemarginpar\fi
   \fi
   \needspace{\baselineskip}\oldmarginnote{#1}%
   \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

MWE (try removing `\needspace{\baselineskip}` to see the difference)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{needspace}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmarginnote\marginnote
\renewcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{%
   \begingroup%
   \ifodd\value{page}
     \if@firstcolumn\reversemarginpar\fi
   \else
     \if@firstcolumn\else\reversemarginpar\fi
   \fi
   \needspace{\baselineskip}\oldmarginnote{#1}%
   \endgroup%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\sloppy

\twocolumn[{%
\hrulefill\medskip\par
\lipsum[1]
\hrulefill
\vspace*{2pc}
}]


\section{Two}\label{s2}
\marginnote{One}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Two}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Three}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Four}\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Five}\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{Six}\lipsum[2]
Some text\par
Some text\par
Some text\par
\marginnote{Seven}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I have now accepted this as an answer. But is there any way if some marginnote which appear on beginning of a line appear properly.

Comment: @JagathAR What do you mean?

Comment: I am sorry. Please read it as "beginning of a page". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JagathAR Oh, I see. See the edit.

Comment: Since there is no comment on the importance of `\begingroup` (w.r.t. to `\reversemarginpar`), https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98126/ may be relevant for anyone adapting this example. Apart from that, excellent answer.

Comment: After changing the document class to ```IEEEtran```, the margin note ```Four``` moves to the left side. Any idea how to prevent this?