# How to get \marginnote to appear in middle margin in two column mode with multicol package?

Tags: floats

I've tried messing around with [How to trigger the marginal note in two column layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230267/how-to-trigger-the-marginal-note-in-two-column-layout)

kind of thing. But still haven't got the marginnotes appearing in the middle column. I would like them aligned with the right or left column (wherever they appear but to be shown in the middle margin which I have made wider.

UPDATE: this old thread is the best so far:

[Two-column document with annotations between columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395205/two-column-document-with-annotations-between-columns)

Comment: I can't quite visualize what you are attempting, but you might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413580/how-to-correctly-change-the-side-that-marginpar-appears-per-case interesting.

Comment: Updating with a link to the best thread on this. Did not find it at first\