# Positioning text on the side of a paragraph

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I would like to be able to place a text besides a paragraph.

The figure below illustrates the scenario:

[image]

I would like to add the text "This is a paragraph comment."  besides a paragraph. But I would not like to hard-code the position of this text in the page; I want instead to be able to tell LaTeX that this particular comment should go along with this specific paragraph.

I could imagine a command like this:

```
\paragraphnote{This is a paragraph comment} Sed blandit justo vel justo blandit convallis. (...)
```

However I do not know whether such a command exists, or how it could be defined -- furthermore, I do not know whether there is a different command, with a different approach, that do what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried `\marginpar`?

Comment: The suggested link produces a paragraph that could be on the right side of the main text, depending on whether the page number is odd or even.  This question asks specifically for a note on the left.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Does it? I don't see anything about left or right placement in the question, it only seems to request placement "beside" a paragraph.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger -- Observe the visual.  The paragraph occupies space left empty by the indentation of the main text past the section headings.  The space for marginpar is likely to be considerably narrower.  This is more like a set-in figure, although `wrapfig` doesn't seem quite the thing for this.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thank you all for your engagement and support! The suggestion given by @Mensch addressed my issue. With some adaptation here and there, I _almost_ managed to do what I was trying to. I said "almost" because there was a detail that I did not mention before: my layout is twoside and for some reason marginnote is not working fine with it. But for this I will create a new question, including a proper example.

Comment: BTW, a solution for the issue with twoside layout is presented here --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226847/making-marginnote-to-appear-either-side-of-twocolumn-twoside-document