# Margin notes on the right side only

Tags: marginpar

I would like to know how I could have margin notes only on the right side of my document using a twoside document class. This is a part of my preamble :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
```

Comment: It could be done using tikzpagenodes (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163567/margin-notes-multicols-tikz-overlay) assuming there is enough room on both sides.

Comment: See the `tabto` package at http://ctan.org/pkg/tabto-ltx.  With syntax like `\tabto*{x-location}` and `\tabto{\TabPrevPos}` for returning to where you left off, you should be able to get what you wish.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done quite easily using KOMA option `twoside=semi`.

[image: domiClassicthesisTwosideSemi]

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,%<---------
    headinclude,footinclude=true,open=any
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}%<--- for testing only

\begin{document}

\chapter{Walzing Wombat}
\blindtext\marginpar{pogo penguin}
\chapter{Rock and Roll Rabbit}
\blindtext\marginpar{Samba Snake}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a layout similar to questions in Walter Pauk's book *How to Study in College*

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=7cm,asymmetric,marginparsep=10mm]{geometry}
\normalmarginpar %Use \reversemarginpar to change to side of \marginpar.
```

This is an global setting, i.e. won't be limited to the current group/environment.

However `\normalmarginpar` switches back to the normal side.

[image: margin notes only on the right side[1]

Based on the great answer provided by Martin Scharrer.

[How can I add margin notes on inner side of a page only for even pages in two sides mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22538/how-can-i-add-margin-notes-on-inner-side-of-a-page-in-two-sides-mode?rq=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145403)

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow Thank for your feedback. I have improved my answer, provided MWE code and a picture of the resulting document.